# InfluxDB batch insert only inserts the last line

Tags: insert, csv, influx-db

I'm trying to insert some lines into a InfluxDB instance (running on Windows 7 x64) from both a .txt and a .csv file, but it's only inserting the last line on the file.

I'm currently using the Insomnia interface to send the file through Influx's HTTP API.
Example:

I have the following content inside a data.txt file:

```
any,mytag=ab value=59
any,mytag=ab value=78
any,mytag=ab value=102
```

All lines are ending with LF only (verifying it through N++).
Then I send this file via an HTTP request to my running InfluxDB instance:

```
POST http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb&precision=ns
```

Yet, when I do a `select * from "any"` query, it shows that only the last line (value=102) was inserted. I've also tried inserting through text/plain content but to no success as well.

Any idea on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested it out and apparently you need the timestamps on the end of each line. Thus the file should look like:

```
any,mytag=ab value=59 1555003566890381500
any,mytag=ab value=78 1555003566890381500
any,mytag=ab value=102 1555003566890381500
```

Now I wonder if you can insert them without the timestamp.